# Update github repository description via graphql

Tags: graphql, github-graphql

This is the GraphQL query for GitHub's API:

```
mutation {
    updateProject(input: {
         projectId: "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMTY0ODYzMDc",
         body: "Testing tusting",
         state: OPEN
    }) {
   clientMutationId
   }
}
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
 "message": "Could not resolve to Project node with the global id of 'MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMTY0ODYzMDc'.",
```

What is wrong here? I'm trying to update a repository description.

Comment: Are you querying this in [Altair](https://altair.sirmuel.design/)? Are you sure the `projectId` is correct?

Comment: I've used repository id, by which I can add/remove star on repository just fine. Isn't it same thing repository and project?
and No I am using GitHub graphQL explorer which is same.

Answer (score 1):

Your question title mentions "repository description", but the GraphQL query is full of "project" references. If you want to update a repo description, you need to use mutation [`updateRepository`](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#updaterepository).